# Is it possible to get the text between the " " from an attribute

Tags: r, regex, rselenium

Can I get the text between " " using RSelenium?

```
<note day="12" month="11" year="2002"
to="Tove" from="Jani" heading="Reminder"
body="Don't forget me this weekend!">
</note>
```

For example: The "12" from the day attribute or the "11" from the month attribute.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

RSelenium is more a tool for getting content from dynamic websites. You could parse the content using `rvest`.

To get all attributes, use `xml_attrs()`. Assuming your XML is saved to a file named "mydata.xml":

```
library(rvest)
read_xml("mydata.xml") %>% 
  xml_nodes(xpath = "//note") %>% 
  xml_attrs()

[[1]]
                            day                           month                            year 
                           "12"                            "11"                          "2002" 
                             to                            from                         heading 
                         "Tove"                          "Jani"                      "Reminder" 
                           body 
"Don't forget me this weekend!"
```

Use `xml_attr()` for individual attributes:

```
read_xml("mydata.xml") %>% 
  xml_nodes(xpath = "//note") %>% 
  xml_attr("day")

[1] "12"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm using it in a dynamic web page.
When using rvesti get: 

Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  AttValue: " or ' expected [39]

Comment: OK, my answer stands, you'd use `RSelenium` to get the content, `rvest` to parse it. We need to see fully reproducible code to debug your error.